# Flume conflicts hadoop with SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings

Tags: hadoop, flume

I am having this messages between Flume, Hive and Hadoop when I start Flume every time. what is the best way to avoid this? I was thinking to remove one jar from flume lib directory but not sure if that going to effect others (hive, hadoop) or not.

```
Info: Sourcing environment configuration script /usr/local/flume/conf/flume-env.sh
Info: Including Hadoop libraries found via (/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop) for HDFS access
+ exec /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java -Xms100m -Xmx200m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -cp '/usr/local/flume/conf:/usr/local/flume/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/usr/local/hadoop/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar' -Djava.library.path=:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native org.apache.flume.node.Application --conf-file /usr/local/flume/conf/spooling3.properties --name agent1
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/flume/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
```

Comment: You should just be able to remove the /usr/local/flume/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar jar (or the hadoop one). 


Flume adds those all to the classpath as well as your hadoop jars so everything should be able to access the jar in the hadoop distribution.

Answer (score 0):

The log messages you have mentioned may be treated as "ordinary warning messages". (No error.)

If you take a look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLUME-2913 , you can see some further explanation.

The way the classpath is constructed for Apache Flume is: `bin/flume-ng` bash script collects all the classpaths from HBase and HDFS and combines them with Flume's own classpath.

If there is a different slf4j jar anywhere, you will see the warning.